# For in javascript and cshtml not working normaly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on asp.net MVC and I have a weird problem that I really don't understand...

At the beginning of my cshtml, I have create a int like this :

```
@
{
int i = 0;
}
```

Then further in my code, I use this variable in a javascript section to create a google chart with a variable number of column and I do it this way :

```
for(var j=0; j<@ViewBag.nbTechs;j++)
{
    data.addColumn('number', '@ViewBag.techs[i]');
    @if (i != 1000)
    {
        i = i+1;
    }
}
```

> ```
> @ViewBag.nbTechs  is equal 9
> ```
>
> `@ViewBag.techs is a list of strings that contains 9 strings`

This code creates me a charts with 9 column but only with the name of the first string in the `@ViewBag.techs` variable...

I have checked if the varible `i` is well updated and yes it is... So I really don't understand why it's only taking the first name ...

Hope someone can help me and thank you in advance

EDIT : output (first string in list)

[image]

Comment: Does `'@ViewBag.techs[j]'` give you the correct output?

Comment: '@ViewBag.techs[i]'  i think you need to take that out from single quote since it is not a string, also there should be ViewBag.techs[j]

Comment: Can't you just use the j from the `for` loop in the `addColumn()`? `data.addColumn('number', '@ViewBag.techs[j]');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke if I put j, it's not working... It's not looking for the j in the for loop but a local variable ( in @() ) :s

Comment: @Ripun it's only working with the quotes :s  if I remove them nothing appears on my page

Comment: @Pimskie as I said to Stephen, j is not working :s

Comment: what is current output of data ??

Comment: @MrPixel6, The problem is that `i` is a c# variable (its not declared as a javascript variable). What you would need to do is to convert `ViewBag.techs` to a javascript array first and them use that in the loop

Comment: So use `var techlist = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.techs))'` then you can use `data.addColumn('number', techlist[j]);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's working better ! But now it's taking letter by letter not string by string

Comment: That does not really make sense if `ViewBag.techs` is a collection - are you sure its `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's a List<string>

Comment: @StephenMuecke  It's ok I found my mistake I putted a char in a wrong place while typing ^^' Thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'@ViewBag.techs[i]'` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so that evaluates to `'@ViewBag.techs[0]'` (view the source code to confirm) so you only ever get the first value in the list.

Remove your `@{ int i = 0; }` code, and instead convert you collection to a javascript array

```
var techlist = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.techs))
for(var j = 0; j < @ViewBag.nbTechs; j++)
{
    data.addColumn('number', techlist[j]);
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the quotes in '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.techs))' It's not working but without it, it's perfect ;) thank you