# Razor Syntax Switching

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am coding in MVC Core and attempting to implement a JavaScript function, which takes the parameter 'stationName'. When I attempt to use 'stationName' within my function, I get errors due to the requirement to switch to C# when reading the data out of my model in the Foreach loop.

Or to say it differently... I want to use my JavaScript parameter in the .Where method of my model.

In this example, stationName cannot be found:

```
// Script - JavaScript
function drawChart_Line(stationName) 
{
    @foreach (var item2 in Model.LineChart.Where(m => m.StationName == stationName)
    {
        <My Code...>
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following, but then my model returns an error:

```
@foreach (var item2 in Model.LineChart.Where(m => m.StationName == @:stationName ))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

X22

Comment: you cannot do that

Comment: Hi Ehsan, do you have any examples of an alternative approach?

Comment: You would need to write a web service (controller method) that takes `stationName` as a parameter and returns (JSON) data for your javascript app to consume via AJAX.

Comment: you have to use different approach, for example send an ajax call and get filtered records in view, so that you just have to use it in view

Comment: You can assign the collection to a javascript array (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471779/for-in-javascript-and-cshtml-not-working-normaly/36472470#36472470)) and then loop over the array.